# One more column into join table using hibernate many-to-many

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, many-to-many

How i can map structure like this
[db model http://imagepost.ru/images/186/oefb4v6.png](http://imagepost.ru/images/186/oefb4v6.png)
into

```
class A{
    Map<SomeEnum, B> foo;
}
```

where key in *foo* is representation of *role* in *a*_ *has* _*b* ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the name of the enum constants in your table column:

```
<hibernate-mapping ...>
...
  <typedef name="role" class="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
    <param name="enumClass">SomeEnum</param>
    <param name="type">12</param>
  </typedef>
...
  <class name="A" table="a">
...
    <map name="foo" table="a_has_b">
      <key column="a_id"/>
      <map-key type="role" length="20" column="role"/>
      <many-to-many class="b" column="b_id"/>
    </set>
...
  </class>
...
  <class name="B">
...
  </class>
...
</hibernate-mapping>
```